# How to solve decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>] occurred due to large input number?

Tags: python, cryptography, integer, secret-key, largenumber

I am having an issue with handling large integers. I am trying to implement threshold secret sharing scheme by following the article in the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-shamirs-secret-sharing-scheme-in-python/). I have modified the driver code to the following so that our secret key is practically large number instead of some pass phrase.

```
t, n = 3, 5
secret = 5238440126074724526414965738603764307730944402353374454036086258591065307597
print(f'Original Secret: {secret}')
shares = generate_shares(n, t, secret)
print(f'Shares: {", ".join(str(share) for share in shares)}')

pool = random.sample(shares, t)
print(f'Combining shares: {", ".join(str(share) for share in pool)}')
print(f'Reconstructed secret: {reconstruct_secret(pool) }')
```

I am getting the following error at due to line `return int(round(Decimal(sums), 0))` from `reconstruct_secret` function :

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

But it works just fine when I shorten my secret to **5238440126074724526414965**. I have no idea how I can modify the **reconstruct_secret** function to work according to my requirement. Any suggestions would be a great help.

Comment: By default the precision of Decimal is 28 digits. If you want to work with longer numbers, you need to increase this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar, my problem was solved by increasing the precision of decimal module as follows:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 100
```

Now I am able to reconstruct secret keys as per my requirement.